# Create Dynamic Database Connection in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, dbconnection

I tried to change the database connection from laravel model,

This  is my code,

```
namespace App\model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Config;
use DB;
class Process extends Model
{

    config(['database.connections.newsql' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => 'gps_bizspecific',
            'username' => 'root'
        ]]);
```

But I got an error

> syntax error, unexpected 'config' (T_STRING), expecting function
>   (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

How to solve this ???

> NOTE : I dont want to update config/database.php., I need to pass the
>   database name (stored in a section variable) from model

**Situation** :

**`When a user register in my site it will create a dedicated database for each user, so when each user login to my site i need to fetch datas from corresponding user database`**

> I have a central database with all user details and database names,
>   when a user login I fetch the datatabse name from the central database
>   and stored it into a session variable. after that I need to create a
>   connection with that new database

Thank you.

Comment: Create one function and then put this code in it!

Comment: just remove in top `use Config;`  because u are using config helper function

Comment: @HirenGohel not working

Comment: @JigneshJoisar not working

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A: Please check my answer below!

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A: Can you please let us know why you want to pass database name? What's your usage of it for further?

Comment: @HirenGohel Sure, When a user register in my site it will create a dedicated database for each user, so when each user login to my site i need to fetch datas from corresponding user  database

Comment: But this is not a good idea to create a database for each user! You can manage it in one database as well and get their data from user id! Think if there's thousands of user and how can you manage all database for all of the users?

Comment: @HirenGohel Its a huge Project , One single database contain more than 100 tables and it is hosted in different countries, so I can't manage the all datas with a single database thats why..........

Comment: You can get database name using: `\DB::getDatabaseName();` and then return it so that you can get it in your controller OR you can directly use it in your controller.

Comment: @HirenGohel I have a central database with all user details and database names, when a user login I fetch the datatabse name from the central database and stored it into a session variable. after that I need to create a connection with that new database

Comment: Ok, please see this one tutorial: https://lukevers.com/2015/03/25/on-the-fly-database-connections-with-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

> Just simply enter the db details in **.env** file

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=yourdbname DB_USERNAME=yourusername DB_PASSWORD=password
```

> then enter below command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: I can't write a static connection